# Unable to start MySQL with SSL support

Tags: mysql-8.0, ssl, tls-1.2

I've generated a handful of certificates for my MySQL 8.0.30 (mysql-server.x86_64 8.0.30-1.module+el8.6.0+16523+5cb0e868 @rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms) on RHEL 8.7 and I'm running into an issue...

I have my ca.pem which contains the root and intermediate certificates, server-key.pem which contains the RSA key (BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY/END RSA PRIVATE KEY) and server-cert.pem which contains the actual server certificate. I'm getting the following error when I start up MySQL:

```
2023-03-19T11:36:56.572166Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013595] [Server] Failed to initialize TLS for channel: mysql_main. See below for the description of exact issue.
2023-03-19T11:36:56.572209Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed
2023-03-19T11:36:56.641677Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011302] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Failed at SSL configuration: "SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key"
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... anyone?

Comment: from the error message you posted: `SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key` go and create this certificate

Comment: which one? the actual exception relates to what I believe ate dh keys but I don't know for sure

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I pulled the source for mariadb (I know it isn't the same but it's close enough) and found the following:

```
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:#include <openssl/dh.h>
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:/* the function below was generated with "openssl dhparam -2 -C 2048" */
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:DH *get_dh2048()
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    static unsigned char dhp_2048[] = {
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    static unsigned char dhg_2048[] = {
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    DH *dh = DH_new();
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    BIGNUM *dhp_bn, *dhg_bn;
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    if (dh == NULL)
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    dhp_bn = BN_bin2bn(dhp_2048, sizeof (dhp_2048), NULL);
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    dhg_bn = BN_bin2bn(dhg_2048, sizeof (dhg_2048), NULL);
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    if (dhp_bn == NULL || dhg_bn == NULL
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:            || !DH_set0_pqg(dh, dhp_bn, NULL, dhg_bn)) {
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:        DH_free(dh);
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:        BN_free(dhp_bn);
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:        BN_free(dhg_bn);
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    return dh;
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:  "SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed",
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    DH *dh= get_dh2048();
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    if (!SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh(ssl_fd->ssl_context, dh))
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:      DH_free(dh);
server-10.9/vio/viosslfactories.c:    DH_free(dh);
```

So it looks like the DHparam wants to get generated at 2048. However, my server is configured for CIS Level 2, and the OpenSSL SECLEVEL is set to 3 (which would require a minimum 3072 bit key). Changing the SECLEVEL to 2 resolves the issue.

Thanks everyone!